# make files uploaded with carrierwave accessible only to activeadmin users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, carrierwave

I am uploading some files with carrierwave

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :pdf_file, MyPdfUploader

class MyPdfUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
end
```

I now want to have access to this file only for activeadmin authenticated users.
What is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

By default Carrierwave will store files in a subfolder of public/ therefore making the files accessible. You can set the store_dir to something like:

```
def store_dir
  "#{Rails.root}/private/pdfs/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
end
```

Then in your activeadmin resource file you can make it available through a custom member_action like:

```
member_action :download, :method => :get do
  if resource.pdf_file.present?
    send_file(
      IO.read(resource.pdf_file.file.path), 
      :filename => "#{resource.pdf_file.filename}", 
      :type => resource.pdf_file.content_type
    ) and return
  else
    flash[:notice] = "No pdf present"
    redirect_to resource_path and return
  end
end
```